# Error running application using Oracle Forms Standalone Application Launcher (FSAL)

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

I'm triggering an Oracle form using frmsal.jar for running the Form without browser.
As soon as I run the below frmsal command
java -jar frmsal.jar -url "http://localhost:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=standaloneapp" -t 10000

FRM-91145: fatal error in runtime process: missing serverArgs parameter
Contact your system administrator.

Comment: share the solution if you found any